# Alternative solution to null layout manager when absolute positioning is needed

Tags: java, css-position, resize, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Few months ago i read this Swing tutorial http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/resizablecomponent/ for understanding how implementing resizable components inside Swing.

The tutorial tells about using a null LayoutManager in order to have the possibility of absolute positioning child components.

In a discussion relative to another subject @Andrew Thompson pointed out that using null layout is a bad idea. This article http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html describe null layout manager as not desirable too, anyway it says that in certain situations the might be useful.

In a situation where:

1. i need absolute positioning for a JPanel's child components
2. i need to implement my own bounding box conditions for child components (in order to establish possible overlapping situations )
3. i need JPanel's child component be resizable

Is correct in the described situation use a null layout manager?

Or there are other better solutions to achieve that goals using a layout manager for my JPanel container component?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best solution would be to implement your own `LayoutManager` (or extend an existing one, if one is really close to your needs) using the features and controls you are looking for.  Your absolute positioning requirements would simply become a method of your layout manager.

For instance, I have, in the past, followed techniques to extend `FlowLayout` to give it abilities to properly wrap elements when contained in a `JScrollPane`.  [Here is an example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), although this is not the same one that I used.